# android sqlite multiple search of records

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on a symptoms checker android application where user can check as many symptoms he may be having. Please do check what I have tried so far:

```
   public String getData(String[] symptoms) {
    String search = "";
    Cursor c = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] 
            {KEY_CONDITIONS}, KEY_SYMPTOMS + "= ? ", symptoms, null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();

    while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
        search += c.getString(0) + ", ";
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    return search;

}
```

but I will need to generate that where string dynamically, because I don't know how many symptoms will be selected. How will I accomplish this? Help from you will truly be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is you **must** have *one* insertion character (`?`) for *each* String in your Array.

One solution is to use a loop:

```
String where = KEY_SYMPTOMS + " = ?";
String relation = " OR "; /* Maybe " AND "? */

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(where);
for(int i = 1; i < symptoms.length; i++)
    builder.append(relation).append(where);

Cursor c = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] 
        {KEY_CONDITIONS}, builder.toString(), symptoms, null, null, null);
```

You can also write a shorter but equivalent loop:

```
while (c.moveToNext())
    search += c.getString(0) + ", ";  // A StringBuilder should be faster
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. How about to limit the repeating records from the result?

Comment: Use a different [`query()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method that has a limit.  (Add `, "10"` to the end of your curreny `query()`.)

Comment: I mean if the user selects more than one symptom, and if the condition/disease has many symptoms, of course that condition will display more than once based on the user's selected symptoms.

Comment: Can you also show me how to do it? Sorry I'm kinda new to database programming.

Comment: I don't know your table's layout, so this is hard to understand your question. But if the condition "Flu" has symptoms like "Fever", "Headache", "Cough" and the user selects "Cough" and "Headache" then "Flu" will only be in the Cursor once, not twice.

Comment: But in my case, it's displaying twice :(

Comment: Hmm, that's not how SQL should work... unless you have duplicate rows by accident.

Comment: Yes I have duplicate records. I included distinct - set it to true. then it worked well. thanks